# Appalling JavaScript Load Times

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, zurb-foundation

I'm scratching my head a little over this one.

I've just started work on a new project.  It's a really simple asp.net MVC site.  In order to be responsive I've gone with Zurb-Foundation (which I've used before, and found to be really good).

My problem - crazy-slow load times for JS and CSS.  We're talking 20 seconds plus for files less than 1KB.

My files aren't minified yet (the project is still at an early stage, and I don't like minifing early on).  I'm using TypeScript for my client-side code, and JQuery and a couple of Foundation scripts.

Does anyone have any ideas?  I've not really come across performance this poor before, especially from such small files.

Comment: If the files are small, it's likely a problem on the server. It doesn't depend on Javascript or Zurb.

Comment: @MaxArt - I did consider this, perhaps I should have mentioned in the question.  Get this issue running locally with full IIS, and IIS Express.  Other projects perform as expected

Comment: Do you experience that for *every* request? How many requests are performed when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to open up the website in chrome dev tools and see what's causing it to take it so long:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that - use dev tools a lot.  I was just seeing 'pending' for 20 plus seconds.  See my answer above - everything has magically sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

Going to put this down as a mystery.

Everything is fine today - without making a single change to anything!